# How to prove that a graph with degree of each vertex equal to 4, has a Hamiltonian cycle?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

I need to this for my homework and I've been looking for over an hour but don't really know where to start. A tip would be appreciated!

Assume we have the following graph:

[image: graph 1]

How can you prove that it has a Hamiltonian cycle?

I know there exists a Hamiltonian cycle (drawn below)

[image: Hamiltonian cycle graph]

Comment: You have already proved it.

Comment: You just gave an example of a such cycle... Done! ;)

Comment: You prove that the graph has a Hamiltionian cycle by finding one.

Comment: I have to prove my claim but I don't know how. And since my drawing is my claim it is no sufficient prove

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A *complete* (simple) graph is one in which each vertex is connected to each other. It's known that every complete graph on more than two vertices is hamiltonian. Since your graph is complete, it follow from that it has a hamiltonian cycle.

As I recall, there's also a theorem like: If the sum of degrees of every two distinct vertices is at least $n$ in an $n$ vertex graph it has a hamiltonian cycle.

Comment: The theorem you are thinking of is called Ore's Theorem, and the condition applies to only nonadjacent vertices, hence it is trivially satisfied in the complete graph!

Comment: @BobKrueger Thanks, I found the thing in a graph theory book but forgot the details.